# Applicability of L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: limits, derivatives, indeterminate-forms

The derivation of L'Hôpital's rule requires Cauchy's theorem, which, in turn, requires the following conditions:

two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ must be continuous and differentiable in an interval $[a,b]$, and $g'(x)\neq 0$

If we have an indetermination for the limit

$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} $$

but, after applying L'Hôpital's rule, we get the indetermination

$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = \frac{f'(a)}{g'(a)} = \frac{0}{0} $$

why can we apply L'Hôpital's rule again to $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ to solve the indetermination $\frac{0}{0}$, if the condition of Cauchy's theorem that $g'(x)\neq 0$ is broken?

Comment: It's quite possible for $g'(x)\ne0$ but $\lim g'(x)=0$ to be true.

Comment: We need differentiability and non vanishing of $g'$ on $(a, b) $ and not on $[a, b] $. So there is no problem

Comment: Also we are supposed to evaluate the limit of $f'(x) /g'(x) $ as $x\to a$ and not evaluate it at $x=a$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh that is what I thought, but the textbook I am reading clearly states [a,b] so I got confused.